# ZK framework - no content in include

Tags: zk

We have a tabbox whose tabpanels use `include` to include content:

```
    <tabpanels height="100%">
        <tabpanel>
            <include src="@load(vm.myTabUrl)"  />
        </tabpanel>

        ...

    </tabpanels>
```

Once in a while in production, the content of the include is not displayed. This behavior seems to be random and we don't know how to replicate it.

When it happens, the generated html contains a `<div>` for the include which only contains another empty `<div>` with class `z-tmp`:

[image: generated html]

ZK doesn't show any errors while rendering and neither does the javascript console. Also there are no failed http (zkau) requests. Any ideas?

Comment: is the source correctly loaded from the VM? If not sure, add a hidden label what reffers to the same vm.myTabUrl. Like that, you can already rule that out (but I'm thinking that's the problem)

Comment: Please show how you define and set vm.myTabUrl in java.

Answer (score 0):

- ZK Client Engine is responsible for conversion of ZUL to HTML at client side.
- ZK has a huge in-built component support compared to HTML. But the things that are displayed on Client side will be HTML itself.

We design a page in ZUL and it is converted into HTML in action. ZUL Components are larger than HTML components in number but in the end we get HTML components only with some changes in their structure.

How the ZUL page reconstructed to HTML page ?

1. ZUL page  are converted to Div, input, anchor mostly.
   ex: Groupbox
   (ZUL)  --> Multiple Div (HTML)
2. The ID of the DOM components are dynamically generated after conversion like z_p5,z_g3 and the ID
   i.e given in ZUL page can be added at AID of the Component.
3. The DOM component can be allowed to have multiple styles separated
   by spaces.
4. The Widget name is added to the component style as z-widget along
   with our regular styles mentioned in ZUL page. The ZK Component name is added as z-widget  in the style attribute of generated HTML DOM Component. As you have already seen that z-include is added in the style attribute of Div element in the above screenshot after generation 
   of page.

---

Coming to the Actual problem,

1. Open the AfterCompose method of the ViewModel of this page.
2. Assign myTabUrl directly with another ZUL page path and Notify it with 
   postNotifyChange method from below.

BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null, null, ClassName.this, "myTabUrl");

May be Variable is not properly assigned or Notifying the variable may be missed which caused this problem. If possible post the ZUL and VM code here if problem still not resolved after this trial.